# Split Contract Design Pitfall

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Due to out-of-gas during deployment, I plan to split one large contract into two: contract A to keep state and is not meant to store any ETH, any state change functions are modified to be allowed to call from contract B only

Contract B is meant to receive/withdraw ETH and be public facing. Its withdraw function will validate the corresponding state in contract A before proceeding with msg.sender.transfer(_validatedAmount).

The question is: Could there be any pitfall of this design to split state and ETH into two contracts this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points that immediately come into mind:

1) Make contract A functions **internal** or verify the calls are coming from address of contract B.

2) If you go with second approach, **delegate** the verification i.e. a call to update address function will change B address in A. This way you don't have to keep redeploying A.

3) make **payable** **fallback** for A incase someone is generous to send eth in A

4) I don't know the exact use case but I am sure you will share some object information. be **careful** and make sure proper checks are present.

5) In the end write good test cases

Your end goal should be that contract A private information is inaccessible to rest of the world. Even one leak can be heavy. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Good points from blockwala. It seems like you would like contract A to be
a *library*, which is a special contract in Solidity that lets you delegate
calls from one contract to another.
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#libraries

Delegate calls don't save the address of contract B calling to A,
and it uses the code of A to operate on the state of B, so if you want to
prevent other contracts from using your library, or want A to keep common
state across multiple contracts B, you might want to keep your current
model of Contract A and Contract B.

You now deploy Library A separately from (and before) Contract B, splitting gas costs
as you desired, and you have an extra linking step of substituting the address of A
into B, before deploying it.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-the-compiler.html?highlight=library%20link